# Service Fabric - Main Method not called

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am building a Service and I want to deploy it to my local 1-Node-Cluster. As soon as I publish my Service to the local cluster, the cluster fails with the following error:

```
Partitions - Error - Unhealthy partitions: 100% (1/1), MaxPercentUnhealthyPartitionsPerService=0%.

Partition - Error - Unhealthy partition: PartitionId='...', AggregatedHealthState='Error'.

Event - Error - Error event: SourceId='System.FM', Property='State'. Partition is below target replica or instance count. fabric:/MyFabric/MyFabricService 1 1 ...

(Showing 0 out of 0 replicas. Total up replicas: 0.)
```

The strange thing is this: I set a breakpoint at the very beginning of my Main-Method, and it never triggers, i.e. the Main Method of my Service is never called.

I read that comparable issues might show up when you have to little memory or disc space available. The system I am running on has 10 GB RAM and 80 GB free disc space, so I think this cannot be the issue here.

Any idea what might be wrong? Ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Are you right-clicking on "Publish" to get it to your local cluster or "Debug -> Start new instance"?

Comment: It just means your service failed to start. Something in your code is causing it to crash.

Comment: I used Publish! But we also tried "Debug - Start Debugging". Same problem. @Vaclav: We are using the same code on a different machine, and it works fine. Therefore I assume something is wrong with the configuration of my local cluster, or with my certificates. Any ideas?

Comment: @Christian have you looked at the Diagnostics Events view in VS while starting the service?  You'll sometimes see messages there, related to failures to start.

Comment: Could very well be something environmental that is causing your EXE to crash, even as simple as not having the right .NET Framework installed (this is common in Azure when you try to deploy a service on .NET 4.6+ onto a 2012 R2 VM image that only has .NET 4.5.2). Check your Windows Event Viewer for Warnings or Errors under Windows Logs -> Application.

Comment: It works now. It seems that something was wrong with my windows installation. Basically I went into recovery mode, reinstalled everything and now it works. Very strange though!